# Having troubles with converting time in iso using java

Tags: javascript, java, datetime, datetime-format, iso

I use the below code to format date time in iso format using java (I'm reducing 1 min from current time) and get the output as this "2016-03-17T11:38:21.xxxZ" < x represent some numbers> i want this to compare with the time which have mentioned in the DB.

Person who build that data insert query, he used javascript to get the time and format it in iso.

Date inside the DB is looks like this "2016-03-17T06:09:21.530Z" and its actual time is "11:39:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" which is similar to my current time but I'm comparing these two dates as string. and get 1min early data from DB.In that case i can't get an out put because as strings these two aren't match. can anybody recomand a solusion ?
I use OrientDB

Java Code

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        long t = date.getTimeInMillis();
        date.setTimeInMillis(t);
        date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, date.get(Calendar.MINUTE) - 1);
        String time1minEarly = df.format(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Use `LocalDateTime` class. The `toString()` of `LocalDateTime` give ISO format output.

Comment: where are the code where you are comparing the two strings? Post a complete example from reading the db to comparing the two strings

Comment: no. It's complicated. We are using 3rd party function to access DB (to insert and write data). all i can do is input date and time as string. and the operation (>,<,= & etc.) then function return the result as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Using Calendar.set() and Calendar.get() does not modify the date in a way you intend:

This will modify the minutes field in your case. So subtracting "1" will reduce the minute but not give a viable date for cases where minute initially is zero.

You may just subtract a minutes of milliseconds from your "t" variable to get a true minute offset.

And for ease of use you might also consider following advise from @Prashant and using LocalDateTime class from joda library.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everybody for your support.
I figure out How to do this. it's pretty easy. Both @rpy and @Prashant are correct. Calendar is not suitable for solve my issue. Also LocalDateTime too. but it did help me to figure out the correct way.

@rpy and  @Prashant they both did miss one thing that the javascript time represent the UTC time. that's the issue. (it's 5.5 hours behind compared to my location) so, I figure out this below code. it did what i wanted to do.

It's pretty easy. all you have to do is provide your zone id.
(You can get Zone id using this code : go to the link - http://www.javadb.com/list-possible-timezones-or-zoneids-in-java/)

Also you can choose so many formats by changing "DateTimeFormatter" value.

```
ZoneId UTCzoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC");
ZonedDateTime time1minEarly = ZonedDateTime.now(UTCzoneId).minusMinutes(1);
String UTCtime1minerly = time1minEarly.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
```

Out put is similar to this : "2016-03-17T10:39:21.530Z"

(- UTC time at that time : 2016-03-17T10:40:21.530Z)